# Collapse Dataframe values under one New group

Tags: r, dplyr

I've done some searching for the answer to this but, I am not totally sure how to ask the question so, for the most part, searching has been fruitless.

Lets say I had a DF that looks like this

```
customer, revenue
a, 2000 
b, 2000 
c, 3000 
Microsoft, 4000 
Oracle, 5000
```

I'd like to get a stacked bar plot that has three stacks...Other, Oracle and Microsoft. Other would be the result of collapsing everything that is NOT Microsoft or Oracle and summing the revenue. Microsoft and Oracle would stand on their own.

the bar plot would be one Bar, with an over all value of 16,000 with individual stacks of (Other=7000, Microsoft = 4000, Oracle=5000)

Hopefully that makes sense.

My code right now, would list all customers separately. In reality, there are many more customers here so the bar plot would be unreadable.

```
finalData <- finalData %>% 
group_by(product, customer) %>%
summarize(revenue = sum(revenue))
```

is there some mutate or additonal group_by operation I can perform that will collapse everything not in  standAloneCustomers and name it "other"?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In your question, the 'product' column was not shown in the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `replace` the values other than "Microsoft", "Oracle" to 'Other' and `summarise` to get the `sum` of 'revenue'

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
finalData %>% 
      group_by(product, customer = replace(customer, 
         !customer %in% c("Microsoft", "Oracle"), "Other")) %>%
       summarise(revenue = sum(revenue)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x= product, y=revenue, fill = customer)) +
       geom_col()
```

[image]

#### data

```
finalData <- structure(list(customer = c("a", "b", "c", "Microsoft", "Oracle"
), revenue = c(2000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000), product = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
dat <- read.csv(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
customer, revenue
a, 2000 
b, 2000 
c, 3000 
Microsoft, 4000 
Oracle, 5000 ")


dat %>%
  mutate(customer = if_else(customer %in% c("Microsoft", "Oracle"), customer, "Other")) %>%
  group_by(customer) %>%
  summarize(revenue = sum(revenue)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x='', y=revenue)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = customer), stat = "identity") +
  xlab(NULL)
```

[image: stacked barplot]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution with `aggregate`

```
dfout <- aggregate(.~customer,
                   within(df,customer <- ifelse(customer%in%c("Microsoft","Oracle"),customer,"other")),
                   sum)
```

such that

```
> dfout
   customer revenue
1 Microsoft    4000
2    Oracle    5000
3     other    7000
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(customer = c("a", "b", "c", "Microsoft", "Oracle"
), revenue = c(2000L, 2000L, 3000L, 4000L, 5000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```